# baasbox on openshift error 503

Tags: openshift, mbaas

I have a small problem, i'am trying to install the mbaas "baasbox" on openshift and i'am getting 503 page, what does it could be??

here is the tutorial that i followed [here](http://www.baasbox.com/deploy-baasbox-on-openshift/)

the rhc tail give me

```
[2014-04-11 01:13:50] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-04-11 01:13:50] INFO ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-04-11 01:13:50] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=398035 port=8080
127.8.255.129 - - [11/Apr/2014:01:14:27 EDT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 39915

-> / 127.8.255.129 - - [11/Apr/2014:01:54:06 EDT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0
-> / [2014-04-11 01:57:39] INFO going to shutdown ... [2014-04-11 01:57:39] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

and here is the content of the start file

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
$BASEDIR/stop
rm $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/RUNNING_PID

nohup java -Dorient.baasbox.path=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/baasbox -Dorient.baasbox.admin_password=admin -Dapplication.code=1234567890 -Dhttp.port=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT -Dhttp.address=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP $* -cp "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/baasbox.log  > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/nohup.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem in the baasbox start file.
here is the complete issue https://github.com/baasbox/baasbox/issues/303

the start file was updated in the baasbox repo, this is the new one.

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
$BASEDIR/stop
rm $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/RUNNING_PID

nohup java -Dorient.baasbox.path=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/baasbox -Dorient.baasbox.admin_password=admin -Dapplication.code=1234567890 -Dhttp.port=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT -Dhttp.address=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP $* -cp "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/baasbox.log   &
```